# Clarification on maps in Salesforce

Tags: apex, map

I know this might be a very basic question but i'm pretty confused by this:

```
Map<Id,Account> accountWithOpportunities = 
    new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account]);
```

I have no clue on to where the Opportunities are relevant at all in this map and how they are stored or can be accessed?

Can anyone clear this out for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're stored in a `List<Opportunity>` variable on each Account in the `Map<Id, Account>` you're getting back from the constructor.

You'd access them like this (using a for loop as an example):

```
for (Opportunity o : accountWithOpportunities.get(accountId).Opportunities) {
     // Do stuff
}
```

Here's a [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_foreign_key.htm) in the Apex Developer Guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Account and it's related Opportunities

```
for(Account acc : accountWithOpportunities.values()){
    //Related Opps
    for(Opportunity opp : acc.Opportunities){
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer isn't really different than that which is already accepted.